# Splitting string in java : lookbehind with specified length

Tags: java, regex

I want to split a string after the letter "K" or "L" except when either is followed by the letter "P". Meanwhile, I hope not to split if the substring length less than 4 when the string is split on a location. 
For example:

```
- Input:
AYLAKPHKKDIV

- Expected Output
AYLAKPHK
KDIV
```

Now, I have achieved to split string after the letter "K" or "L" except when either is followed by the letter "P". My regular expression is `(?<=[K|R])(?!P)`.

```
My result:
AYLAKPHK
K
DIV
```

However, I don't know how to ignore the split location where the substring length less than 4.

[My Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vcl44T/1/)

Comment: Just to be sure: does "substring" in "*I hope not to split if the substring length less than 4*" also refer to remaining part? Like in case of `ABCKAB`, should we split it into `ABCK` `AB` or not because of `AB` which would not be at least 4 characters long? Your current example shows similar case but we don't know if it fails because of `K` or (also) because of `DIV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I hope not to split if the substring length less than 4

In other words, you want to have

1. *previous* match (split) separated to *current* match with at least 4 characters, so `ABCKABKKABCD` would split into `ABCK|ABKK|ABCD` not but not into `ABCK|ABK|.....
2. at least 4 characters after *current* split since `ABCKAB` after split `ABCK|AB` would have `AB` at the end which length is less than 4.

To achieve first condition you can use `\G` which represents place of previous match (or start of the string if there ware no matches yet). So first condition can look like `(?<=\G.{4,})` (WARNING: usually look-behind expects obvious maximal length of subregex it handles, but for some reasons `.{4,}` works here, which can be bug or feature added in Java 10 which I am using now. In case it complains about it, you can use some very big number which should be bigger than max amount of characters you expect between two splits like `.{4,10000000}`)

Second condition is simpler since it is just `(?=.{4})`.

BTW you don't want `|` in `[K|R]` as there it represents literal, not OR operator since by default any character in character set is alternative choice. So `[K|R]` represents `K` OR `|` OR `R`. Use `[KR]` instead.

DEMO:

```
String text = "AYLAKPHKKKKKKDIVK123KAB";
String regex = "(?<=[KR])(?!P)(?<=\\G.{4,})(?=.{4})";
for (String s : text.split(regex)){
    System.out.println("'"+s+"'");
}
```

Output:

```
'AYLAKPHK'
'KKKK'
'KDIVK'
'123KAB'
```

Comment: The first condition is that I want to. Thank you for giving your detailed explanation. I appreciate it and I learn more knowledge about regular expression. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `matcher` to *match* each substring, rather than `split`, if possible - you might find logic a bit easier to follow when you can *consume* characters, rather than having to identify a particular *position*. Match three or more characters followed by a (`K` or `R` not followed by `P` with `.{3,}?[KR](?!P)`, ensure that it's followed by at least 4 characters with `(?=.{4})`, OR, if the whole above pattern fails, match the whole rest of the string with `.+$`:

```
String s = "AYLAKPHKKDIV";
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".{3,}?[KR](?!P)(?=.{4})|.+$").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
  arr.add(m.group());
}
```

Comment: I want to use the regular expression to split the text into terms in `elasticsearch` `Pattern Analyzer`, so I have to identify a particular position but thank you for helping me.